# Python Open() and File Handles?

Tags: python, file, read-write

I'm new to Python and I have read a file into memory. I then do a simple loop to see what the contents of the file are....

Then I try to perform another action on the file and it appears it has disappeared or left memory?

Can someone please explain what's going on and how I can store a file in memory to query it?

```
>>> fh = open('C:/Python/romeo.txt')
>>> for line in fh:
...     print(line.rstrip())
...
But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief
>>> for line in fh:
...     print(line)
```

Comment: You could just read it once, e.g. `lines = [line for line in fh]` followed by `fh.close()`.  After that, you can just operate on the list `lines`, which will contain all of the lines of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object returned by `open` acts as its own iterator. When you iterate over its contents, the file pointer remains at the end of the file. That means the second `for` loop *starts* at the end, rather than getting a "fresh" iterator that starts at the beginning.

To iterate again, use the `seek` method to return to the start of the file.

```
>>> fh = open("romeo.txt")
>>> for line in fh:
...   print(line.rstrip())
...
But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief
>>> fh.seek(0)
0
>>> for line in fh:
...   print(line.rstrip())
...
But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief
```

---

Note the difference between the `TextIOWrapper` object returned by `open`:

```
>>> type(fh)
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
>>> type(iter(fh))
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
>>> fh is iter(fh)
True
```

and a list, which is *not* its own iterator.

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> type(x)
<class 'list'>
>>> type(iter(x))
<class 'list_iterator'>
>>> x is iter(x)
False
```

Each call to `iter(x)` returns a *different* iterator for the same list `x`.

Comment: Or just read the contents into memory once, then close it and work from memory after that.

Comment: It's likely already in memory (disk cache), so why make a copy in another Python object?

Comment: It's more flexible.  You can only `seek` certain types of I/O streams.  For example, if this were adapted read from `stdin` (or if `/dev/stdin` were used on systems that support it), or if a socket were used, the `seek` approach would not work.  It also reduces the number of system calls even when it does work.

Comment: That's really a different question. It's not always feasible, or desirable, to immediately consume a stream.

Comment: I would say that if it's small, and if you would otherwise have to `seek` to go back to previously read data, then probably consuming the entire file up front is preferable.  I think that the cases where you don't want to read the whole thing are usually cases where you don't need to `seek`.